# relative acceleration of ball in a train

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

> A boy is standing in a train with a ball in his hand. The train is having a constant acceleration equal to x m/s^2. While still in train he throws the ball with a constant velocity of 20 m/s at an angle of 60 degree with the horizontal and catches it at distance of 1.15 m.(the boy travels that distance)We are intended to calculate the acceleration of train.

solving this question taking ground as frame of reference is not feasible here. So the only option remains is solving with respect to train. My main question is how?
(No need to solve the numerical, kindly explain the concept to be applied.

Comment: Presumably the ball velocity is in the reference frame of the train and the “distance” is how far the train moves with respect to the ground?

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that the boy has to cover that distance and not the train with respect to the ground. so it's the distance with respect to train

Comment: What distance the boy has to cover? He’s standing still with respect to the train isn’t he? If so he can only be moving with respect to the ground just like the train. Maybe I’m missing something

Comment: @Bob D i edited my question. just take a look at it

Comment: So the boy travels 1.15 m with respect to the ground, correct?

Comment: no it travels 1.15 m in the train i.e with respect to ground

Answer (score -1):

You can use the train as a frame of reference as long as you take into account that it is not an *inertial* frame of reference. To account for the acceleration of the train you will have to introduce a *fictitious* force of magnitude $mx$ N acting horizontally on an object of mass $m$ kg. This fictious force is similar to gravity, but it acts horizontally instead of vertically.

The horizontal fictitious force does not affect the ball's vertical motion. You are given the ball's initial velocity so you can work out the time $t$ that it takes for the ball to return to the same height from which it was thrown.

Given $t$ and the distance $s_h$ that the ball travels horizontally (in the reference frame of the train), you can then use the horizontal equation of motion for the ball while it is flight:

$s_h(t) = u_ht - \frac{xt^2}{2}$

to find the value of $x$.